# calibration of a custom robot with a Swissranger

Tags: ros, robot-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am interested in using the pr2_calibration package to calibrate a custom robot.  My robot has a 7 DOF arm, 4 DOF neck, 3 cameras, and a Swiss Ranger flash LIDAR.  I am wondering what is the best way to model the Swiss Ranger for the pr2_calibration package.  It doesn't really fit the existing tilting laser or camera models.  Although, i could probably go in either direction.  Has anyone done this before?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11005/calibration-of-a-custom-robot-with-a-swissranger/) by [baxelrod](https://answers.ros.org/users/86/baxelrod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 794 on 2011-08-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Similar questions http://answers.ros.org/question/102/how-can-i-calibrate-my-real-robot and
http://answers.ros.org/question/840/robot-arm-calibration-for-schunk-7-dof-arm

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0